# How to get values from daterange picker using asp C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

Im trying to get values from daterange picker, the ranges, startDate and endDate.
there part of my code on my content template .ascx

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="reportrange" runat="server" CssClass="DatepickerInput" />


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
    var end = moment();

    function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
    }

    $('.DatepickerInput').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        ranges: {
            'Today': [moment(), moment()],
            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);

    cb(start, end);

});
```

in my File.cs I have this

```
  string value = reportrange.values;
```

Comment: Have console the value of reportrange?

Comment: those values are purely held in JavaScript objects, they are not submitted with your form when you post it to the server. The only value sent to the server is what's actually in the textbox itself, which will be the date the user selected. Therefore there's no way to access them from C#. You'd have to do something extra to send them there, e.g. copy the values into hidden fields, or send them via AJAX or something. Then again, you're hard-coding the calculations of what the ranges etc are, they're predictable (not based on user data) so you could just repeat the same calcs using C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue as follows
converting the datepicker range into a Textbox and getting the text

`<asp:TextBox id="reportrange" runat="server" CssClass="DatepickerInput" Text=" " style="width:100%"></asp:TextBox>`

and the code behind 
get the text and split de start date, end date

```
string date= reportrange.Text;
string d_start= (date.Split('-'))[0];
string d_end = (date.Split('-'))[1];
string start= d_start + " 00:00:00.000";
string end= d_end + " 23:59:59.999";
```